# How to do the Rewiring Framework after OSGi bundle update

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

I have a equinox based application. I need to update a bundle and rewire the OSGi bundles corresponding to the updated bundle.

I updated the bundle using,

```
bundle.update(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)));
```

I need to refresh the affected bundles in order the update to be affected.

How can I do this?...

Answer (score 7):

```
BundleContext bcx = bundle.getBundleContext();
Bundle systemBundle = bcx.getBundle(0);

bundle.update(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)));

FrameworkWiring frameworkWiring = systemBundle.adapt(FrameworkWiring.class);
frameworkWiring.refreshBundles(null);
```

Please note that refreshBundles is an asynchron function call. Therefore if you want to catch the event when the bundles are refreshed, you must pass a FrameworkListener as the second parameter.

Comment: AFAIK this refresh all the bundles right?..Can't we refresh only the affected bundles only??..

Comment: Yes you can, see: http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/FrameworkWiring.html#refreshBundles(java.util.Collection, org.osgi.framework.FrameworkListener...)

Comment: Check the javadoc of the FrameworkWiring.refreshBundles(...) function. The algorithm is well specified there. In short: Only those bundles are refreshed that have to be refreshed (but all those bundles transitively).

Comment: I suppose it can achieved using getDependencyClosure().. then refresh only those bundles. right?.. How does it affect when there are dynamic  imports?.

Comment: I do not know, how dynamic imports behave in case of a refresh. Normally, I not only try to avoid using Dynamic-Import but I also try to avoid using any technology that has Dynamic-Import. I prefer using refreshBundles(null). I do not try finding out, what should be refreshed as I do not want to have a partially-refreshed framework on the end. What if a bundle uninstalls another bundle programmatically in the stop event? If I did not know about it, I would probably not refresh the bundles that use the programmatically uninstalled bundle.

Comment: Dynamic imports are included in the refresh. You also don't need to perform the dependency closure yourself since the refreshBundles method will perform the closure on the specified bundles.

Comment: I use the code your posted and I have problem. I have two bundles A and B. BundleB depends on bundleA. I update bundle A and run your code. And here I have a problem - I see in log that BundleB was stopping, stopped, unresolved, resolved, starting but never(!) started. However, when I do bundleB stop and start many times (I mean without touching bundleA) I don't have any problems. Could you help to solve this problem?

Comment: @Pavel I can imagine a couple of things. Reason 1: Bundle B has "Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy" in its MANIFEST file and it is in remains in starting state. Reason 2: There is a deadlock in the code. Do a thread dump from your JVM and see if any thread is locked during starting your bundle. Reason 3: Any other exception. If you use Equinox, uncaught exceptions are written to special log files in the configuration folder by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem seems to be in thread deadlock in pax-cdi or weld. This is the thread I created https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ops4j/msmgHq0B1l8

Comment: Could you explain the following behavior. I have two bundles: bundleA and bundleB. BundleB depends on bundleA. I update bundleA and after that run your code. Your code does the following: it stops and starts bundleA and stops and starts bundleB. But why bundleA? I am asking because in result poor bundleA is two times updated.

Comment: @Pavel I know only that is written in the javadoc of the refreshBundles(...) function: https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/FrameworkWiring.html#refreshBundles(java.util.Collection, org.osgi.framework.FrameworkListener...) . I am not sure why it restarts bundle A, I guess to get the answer, you should debug the code of your OSGi container (why Bundle A will be in the dependency closure). Another option is to specify Bundle B in the parameter directly.

Comment: @Pavel: In the bundle deployer I wrote I stopped using bundle.update() as it was somehow unstable. Sometimes it could not read the JAR file from the filesystem if "reference:" was used as bundle location. I decided to always uninstall the bundle and install/start it. After it was done, I called refresh with null parameter.